# I want a query to generate the result column below. assume required columns are present in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Result column should increment by 1 when you change a group of empID, DepID. Also the result column should get reset if the days between someDT of 2 consecutive rows is greater than 5 days.

```
CREATE TABLE tab 
(   "empid" NUMBER(5,0), 
"depid" NUMBER(7,0), 
"somedt" DATE
);

Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-JAN-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-FEB-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-MAR-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-APR-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-MAY-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-JUN-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-MAY-12 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,12868,to_date('05-JUN-12 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780018,17023,to_date('05-FEB-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into TAB (EMPID,DEPID,SOMEDT) values (780019,12868,to_date('05-FEB-11 16:54:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Please *do not* post sample data as images. It is hard to utilize data presented as an image.

Comment: I specifically rolled back the changes so the table is now in the query, embedded as text -- the best way to present data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `row_number()`.  However, the conditition on "greater than 5 days" is tricky.  You also need to identify groups of rows.  For that, use `lag()` to find when a group begins.  Then a cumulative sum to specify the groups, and finally `row_number()`:

```
select EmpID, DepID, someDt,
       row_number() over (partition by EmpID, DepId, grp, order by someDt) as Result
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when someDt < prevDt + 5 then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by EmpID, DepId order by someDt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(someDt) over (partition by EmpID, DepId order by someDt) as prevDt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be thinking too complicated. Well, here is my approach:

1. detect desired group break records; mark them with a 1, whereas other records get a 0
2. have a running total on that group break number, so you get numbered groups
3. number the records per group.

Here is the query:

```
select 
  empid,
  depid,
  somedt, 
  row_number() over (partition by grp order by empid, depid, somedt) as result
from
(
  select 
    empid, depid, somedt, sum(chg) over (order by empid, depid, somedt) as grp
  from
  (
    select 
      empid, depid, somedt,
      case when empid = lag(empid) over (order by empid, depid, somedt)
            and depid = lag(depid) over (order by empid, depid, somedt)
            and somedt <= lag(somedt) over (order by empid, depid, somedt) + 5
           then 0
           else 1
      end as chg
    from mytable
  )
);
```